# Hash of segments

Tags: python, hash

I'd like to use a `set()` of segments, defined by two endpoints `p0` and `p1`, but I am afraid my solution will yield wrong results.

I have implemented both `point` and `segment` classes and their respective hash functions. The `point` class is straightforward:

```
def __hash__(self):
    """
    returns the hash of the point
    """
    return hash((self.x, self.y))
```

The `segment` class is tricky, since it should work *regardless of the endpoint order*, so `(p0, p1) == (p1, p0)`. I've implemented the following hash function:

```
def __hash__(self):
    """
    returns the hash of the segment
    """
    return hash((self.p0, self.p1)) | hash((self.p1, self.p0))
```

It works **in my tests** but I am terrified that somehow a problem will rise when I least expect it.

Is there a "good" way of hashing regardless of the order? I am not looking for speed, but I need correctness.

Comment: Sort the points before hashing them…?

Comment: Exclusive-OR of the hashes of the two points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised you didn't think of this yourself:

```
def __hash__(self):
    """
    returns the hash of the segment
    """
    sorted_points = tuple(sorted((self.p0, self.p1)))
    return hash(sorted_points)
```

If you don't have `__eq__()`, `__lt__()`, etc. defined on points, then just make a custom key to sort them the intuitive way, e.g. `key=lambda p:(p.x,p.y)`

As long as the sorting method is deterministic, then order no longer matters - the 'smaller' one will end up in front.

Comment: Thanks, I did actually missed that, don't know why. I have a question: I **do** have an `__eq__` operator defined for both points and segments, point coordinates are capped at a certain precision (10^-5), and are equal if their distance is less than that precision. Segments are equal if their endpoints are the same regardless of the order. Would this `__eq__` on points be a problem?